# Thread.GetNamedDataSlot usage returns unexpected results

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this code that runs 2 threads in parallel and then executes on the main thread

```
var t1 = Task.Run(() => { 
    Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("xxx"),12);
    object data1 = Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("xxx"));
    Console.WriteLine("T1 data: " + data1); 
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
});

var t2 = Task.Run(() => {
    //Thread.Sleep(100);
    object data2 = Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("xxx"));
    Console.WriteLine("T2 data: " + data2);
});

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

object data3 = Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("xxx"));
Console.WriteLine("Base T data: " + data3);
Console.WriteLine("Base T Has data: " + (data3 != null));

Console.WriteLine("DONE");
```

But the result is somewhat unexpected [sometimes]. Periodically I get this printed

> T2 data: 12 **<-- here is my problem**
>   T1 data: 12 
>   Base T data: 
>   Base T Has data: False
>   DONE

According to MS documentation

> ...Data slots are unique per thread. No other thread (not even a child thread) can get that data.

This happens intermittently. But the main thread never gets data.
What do I have (or understand) incorrect?

Comment: `Task.Run` reuses threads from the thread pool, so `t2` may run on a thread that `t1` previously ran on. Are you running this code just once, or multiple times in the same process?

Comment: @kalimag I thought `Task.Run` creates CPU-bound threads every time. If it reuses, then oh-boy. This is just my fiddle. In real life threads will be created by asp.net and if we spin them like in this example, we init them every time. This was just my test how well this could work. Yea, if there is re-usage then I understand this issue. Will read.

Comment: Don't know what you're actually need this for, but you should look into `AsyncLocal<T>`